# Doctrine 2.2.2, cascade not working with many-to-many association?

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony-forms

I'm using Doctrine 2.2.2 on Symfony 2.0.17-DEV and PHP 5.3.14. I've a problem with many-to-many associations with cascade options. Example is so simple, hope than someone from this fantastic board can help me.

Anyway, `Meta` superclass is the owner of a relation with `User`. Relevant field and constructor only:

```php
abstract class Meta
{
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="User", inversedBy="meta")
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="meta_users",
     *     joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(onDelete="CASCADE")},
     *     inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(onDelete="CASCADE")}
     * )
     */
    protected $users;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->users = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function addUser(User $user)
    {
        $this->users[] = $user;
        return $this;
    }

    public function getUsers()
    {
        return $this->users;
    }
}
```

(Implementations, just empty classes, are `Label` and `Category`)

**It's simple and it works, actually**. I mean adding or removing users from a meta actually adds/deletes the corresponding rows in join table.

The problem occurs doing the opposite: creating/editing an user and assigning meta. `User` define the association with meta this way, and adds a cascade="all" option:

```php
class User
{
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Meta", mappedBy="users", cascade={"all"})
     */
    protected $meta;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->meta = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function addMeta(Meta $meta)
    {
        $this->meta[] = $meta;
        return $this;
    }

    public function getMeta()
    {
        return $this->meta;
    }
}
```

I'm quite new to Doctrine, but this is not working. In my Symfony 2 form for creating/editing an `User`, i've added a field of type `entity`, just selecting all meta:

```
$builder
    ->add('meta', 'entity', array(
        'label'         => 'Meta',
        'class'         => 'Acme\HelloBundle\Entity\Meta',
        'property'      => 'select_label',
        'multiple' => true,
        'expanded' => true,
    ))
;
```

No changes on any table when assigning (using checkboxes) meta to an user. What's wrong? I'm sure i'm missing something, but i can't find what.

Answer (score 1):

Speak for what i know.

Cascade option has nothing to do with persisting your join table associations. It's should be used when a new `Meta` entity is found in the relation `meta` for entity `User` (or an old entity is removed). That is when, in your form, you add some input to create new meta or remove existing one, for example using `collection` for field type that Symfony 2 provides). Or just when you do:

```php
$newMeta = new Meta();

$user->addMeta($meta);

$em->persist($user); // A new entity was found in the relation meta
```

As i far as i understand you want to persist the relation itself; Doctrine **always look for the owning side** in order to persist entities. Meaning that **from the inverse side** you want to persist the user first, than persist each meta adding or removing the user if the corresponding checkbox is checked or not.

Your field is `entity` type, meaning all meta are fetched from your table and those already assigned to the user are marked as checked.

I remember doing something similar, here is a "pseudo" controller code:

```php
$em->persist($user); // Perstist the inverse side

// This is what user selected
$selectedMeta = $user->getMeta();

// All meta coming from your database
$allMeta = $em->getRepository('YourBundle::Meta')->find();

// Loop on the owning side
foreach($allMeta as $meta)
{
    // Is current meta selected?
    $isSelected = $selectedMeta->contains($meta);

    // Does this meta have already the user in it?
    $hasUser = $meta->getUsers()->contains($user);

    // To be removed: not selected and with the user
    if(!$isSelected && $hasUser)
        $meta->getUsers()->removeElement($user);

    // To be added: selected and without the user
    if($isSelected && !$hasUser)
        $meta->addUser($user);

    $em->persist($meta); // Persist the owning side and the association
}

// Apply
$em->flush();
```

Waiting for a confirmation too!